# Android Upload imagem em string para c#

Tags: java, c#, android, mobile

Estou enviando imagens do Android para o servidor em C# mas quando tento fazer a conversão dá erro nessa conversão.

No android faço essa conversão:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
final byte[] img_byte = stream.toByteArray();

final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(img_byte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

No servidor c# recebo a string e faço novamente a conversão para imagem:

```
byte[] novaFoto = Convert.FromBase64String(NovaFoto.FotoString);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(novaFoto))
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

As vezes dá erro ao fazer a conversão para **byte[]** e as vezes dá erro no **Image.FromStream**

Alguém pode me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Você está enviando essa string 64 via `POST`, correto? Verificou se ela não está sendo truncada?

Comment: De que maneira posso ver isso?